# Story from greek mythology talking about not being able to change bad habits

Tags: greek, myth-identification

Is there a story from greek mythology which talks about the difficulty to change a bad habit? 
The character involved should be aware that it is a bad habit, but just isn't able to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most famous bad habit of Greek mythology is probably Zeus' promiscuity. Besids 3 wives (Hera being the last), he had many supernatural affairs:

- Aega
- Ananke/Themis (3 offspring)
- Aphrodite
- Demeter
- Dione/Thalassa
- Eris
- Eurynome (3 offspring)
- Gaia (yes it’s true)
- Leto (Apollo and Artemis)
- Maia (Hermes)
- Metis (Athena)
- Mnemosyne (12, yes, 12 offspring)
- Leda/Nemesis (Helen of Troy)
- Persephone (2 offspring)
- Selene (3 offspring)
- Thalia
- Themis
- Eos

and demigods & humans:

- Aegina (2)
- Alcmene (Heracles aka Hercules)
- Antiope (2)
- Anaxithea
- Asterope/Oceanid
- Callisto
- Calyce
- Callirhoe (0)
- Carme
- Cassiopeia
- Chaldene (2)
- Danae
- Dia
- Elara
- Electra (3)
- Europa (6. Honestly, I’m tired.)
- Eurymedousa
- Eurydeia
- Himalia (3)
- Idaea
- Iodame
- Io (2)
- Isonoe
- Lamia
- Lamia, daughter of Poseidon
- Laodamia
- Maera
- Niobe (2)
- Othreis
- Pandora
- Phthia
- Plouto
- Podarge (2)
- Protogeneia (2)
- Pyrrha
- Semele
- Taygete
- Thyia (2)